# Check that an image has 2 colors

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have images which may be monochrome icons (really bichrome: some color icon on some color background), and I need to check if they really are.

Often times the images are low quality, so the pixel values don't actually fall into two distinct groups, even if the image is meant to be monochrome. For instance, say the image is meant to be red on green. I might expect to find unique pixel values (255, 0, 0) and (0, 255, 0). A generic check to make sure any image has two colors only would be something like `np.unique` but making sure we treat each pixel vector as an entity. So something like this:

```py
# some binary valued pixels for demonstration
arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, 60).reshape(20, 3) 
print(f"Number of unique colors: {np.unique(arr, axis=0)}")
```

But with low quality images I'll get smearing around (255, 0, 0), so I might see (254,1,4), (250, 0, 1) etc. And then my method above won't work any more. How can I account for this?

Comment: You could quantize the image down to 2 colours (using K-means for example) and then calculate, for each pixel, the distance to the nearer of those two colours. Tally up all those exceeding some threshold.

Comment: That's a great idea. I was previously discarding K-means as a viable method. Feel free to add as an answer if you like

Comment: Nah! Let's wait till someone clever comes along and tells us a better way

Comment: How about training a neural network with many fully connected convolutional layers, just joking...Or you could use what everybody else uses: RBG histograms

Comment: @Joe [meme](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/012/066/Boardroom_Suggestion_Icon.jpg). Yes I can use a histogram, but then how do I algorithmically determine the answer to my question?

Comment: Check if two or more columns in each layer (array, histogram) are non-zero or above a certain threshold if you also go for similar colors. You could also calculate the mean color in each layer, subtract that from the actual layer and check if the differences are smaller than a certain threshold. Or use the histogram on the array with the differences.

Comment: Or you could use scipy.spatial.distance.pdist to determine the distance between all possible colors (found in the histogram or with np.unique) and bin that result.

Comment: Is there a reason why kmeans isn't a viable answer? It seems like it'd probably solve your problem pretty cleanly. If you don't want to use that then you could convert to hsv before binning the colors. It's a much easier color space for differentiating hues than rgb (just watch out for the wraparound from 0 to 180. Can you post some examples of low quality images?

Comment: @IanChu k means is not bad, there's extra work to do because the spread of pixels can sometimes be tricker than one would expect for an image which looks monochrome to the human eye. My main issue now is differentiating cluster spread from actually having two distinct clusters.

Comment: @Joe good ideas. I'm trying variants of them